# Visual Studio Cordova tools, device debug break points in wrong files

Tags: android, angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-cordova

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 to create an Apache Cordova project. When I am debugging on the device (Android Nexus 6) my breakpoints are not in the correct file.

I have TypeScript bundling to a single file and it has a .map file that appears to have the correct TypeScript files listed in it.

What do I need to do to get the breakpoints in a Cordova project to work correctly with TypeScript?

This is an angular project and it likes to break in my main app.ts file instead of the service.ts file I added the breakpoint to, but the watches all work correctly, its really hard to step through and see where you are.

Comment: This seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698886/tools-for-apache-cordova-typescript-debugger-jumps-to-wrong-line

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes happen also on my system. For fix it I usually clean the browser cache (if was not running in incognito/private), clean the solution and then rebuild it.