# Tools for Apache Cordova - TypeScript debugger jumps to wrong line

Tags: cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

if i create a new BlankCordovaApp TypeScript-Project with Visual Studio 2015 RC and add these two ts files the following modifications to the index.ts and index.html

**aaa.ts**

```
class  AAA {
    add(a: number, b: number) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

**bbb.ts**

```
class BBB {
    mul(a: number, b: number) {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
 export function test() {

     var aaa = new AAA();
     var bbb = new BBB();

     var sum = aaa.add(2, 3);
     var product = bbb.mul(2, 3);

     var result = sum + product;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<button onclick="BlankCordovaApp2.Application.test()">TEST</button>
```

If i run these app on a android emulator or device and set a breakpoint to the first line of the test() function, then the debugger jumps to the last line of the bbb.ts file. Other breakpoints behave the same :(

What is wrong with the demo project? These behavior exists since i switch from the VS2015 CTP to the RC Version.

Regards

Comment: I cannot reproduce on my side with VS2015 RC. How did you get the RC version installed? Directly upgrade or remove then install? It is recommended to remove then install.

Comment: Im not sure, maybe i'm to old ;) but i believe it was a upgrade. 
So you have no problem with the debugging of larger Typescript Cordova apps?

Comment: I have no idea how large the project should be. But if you saw the issue with so simple project but I didn't, I think it is related to your environment and likely be the VS installation issue(something was not updated successfully). So do you mind a re-installation of VS?

Comment: THx for the Hint Alan, can you tell to with line the debugger jumps if you create a litte coordova test app with the file on top and set a breakpoint to the first line ("var aaa = new AAA();") of the test function in the index.ts?

Comment: The debugger stops at the exact same line.  I record a video to show what I got. check it from my share onedrive video. http://1drv.ms/1Gr0ntJ

Comment: thank you Alan fort tue quick answer. I will check this out, hope i must not install tue komplette VS new :( Can you send me your appBundle.js and appBundle.js.map file form your project. I will compare this against my versions. THX!

Comment: I built the project and uploaded the entrie project in zip at http://1drv.ms/1KoRmTq Look forward to seeing your findings. :)

Comment: Hello Alan, thx for the project. The strange thing is, that it work on my machine as expected. The debugger jumps to the line "var aaa = new AAA();" BUT what happens on your machine if you move the test function OVER the "onDeviceReady()" function and set the brakpoint to the "var aaa = new AAA();"? I can toggle the hehavior of my debugger  with this codemove. If the code stays before the onDeviceReady functions, then my debugger jumps to the wrong line/file.

Comment: Reproduced on my side. I found a similar issue in MS internal bugcheck. Seems a by design issue, it is related to how the debugger gets attached. I will definitely confirm my guessing. Do you have any solid reason that let you put the code before the onDeviceReady function? If not, let's work it around by putting user defined functions after onDeviceReady function.

Comment: Forgot to mention the issue I found in MS internal bugcheck says it is for ripple emulator. And I did a quick check by changing target to windows-x64, no issue with it.

Comment: Hello Alan, thx for the info. My problem is not really the position of the function, because i have a bigger typescript app (build with the ctp version) that starts there initialization in the onDeviceReady() function, after the TODO comment. The app/debugger had worked corrent with the VS CTP version, but after the migration to the RC is the debugger broken :( And i have no idear how i can fix this problems. The problem exists on android/windows phone emulator and real device.

Comment: I tried what you've done in onDeviceReady() afte TODO comment and YES I can produce that. But it will not happen for a javascript cordova app. I fully understand how inconvenient it is with this issue. I will definitely help you to confirm this issue. Will update here once I get any progress.

Comment: Could you please try start debugging in ripple->refresh the entire ripple page and check if the breakpoint hit correctly. And I double confirmed the issue doesn't happen for windows phone emulator, if you still face issue, try set breakpoint in appBundle.js and run window.location.reload() in javascript console.

Comment: Thank you Alan for the help. I usw only typescript and will not migrate the complete app to JavaScript because of these bug/issue. I will try the window.location.reload(), but currently I use ripple only for minimal tests. Because my app use multiple plugins that are not available in ripple. One additional information for u. All .ts files of my app are under the www folder. In the default template they are outside of the www folder because of the appbundle, which contains the complete content.

Comment: Ok i installed my OS (win8.1) from scretch and i also installed the english vs 2015 rc. After that i start my app and the debugging was broken is before :( 
Then i try to disable the appBundle mechanism. I open "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" and remove the line "<TypeScriptOutFile>$(ProjectDir)\www\scripts\appBundle.js</TypeScriptOutFile>. After a restart of VS the typescriptcompile create single files for ever .ts file. I include every js file in my index.html and start the app.

Comment: The debugging works correct. the window.location.reload trick helps me to jump into the onDeviceReady function at the beginning. This is only a workaround to get a working debugging experience and i hope it will be fixed in the final version of vs 2015. I will also create a new demo project to show the issue better.

Comment: This seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836609/visual-studio-cordova-tools-device-debug-break-points-in-wrong-files

Comment: It happens also on my system. In order to fix it, I usually clear the browser cache (or launch in Incognito mode), clean the solution and then rebuild it.